# strncpy is replaced by __strncpy_chk and fails

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, strncpy, fortify-source

I have a statement

```
strncpy(&data->m_bin->data,versionStr,data->m_bin->sizeData);
```

in my application which itself is fine and works well. Here data->m_bin->data is a char where the calling application ensures it is followed by a datablock which is large enough to keep all the data handed over by strncpy().

But when I build this as release using GCC/Linux, this function crashes in __strncpy_chk(). So it seems my strncpy() was replaced by __strncpy_chk() using a wrong length for parameter s1.

So how can I ensure __strncpy_chk() is called with the correct length for s1?

Thanks!

Comment: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL38-C.+Use+the+correct+syntax+when+declaring+a+flexible+array+member might help, or not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `strncpy(&data->m_bin->data,versionStr,data->m_bin->sizeData);`

The `address of` operator looks suspicious to me. I would expect something like:

```
strncpy(data->m_bin->data,versionStr,data->m_bin->sizeData);
```

Or maybe:

```
strncpy(&data->m_bin->data[0],versionStr,data->m_bin->sizeData);
```

---

> how can I ensure `__strncpy_chk()` is called with the correct length for s1?

Well, you can't *per se*. This is part of `FORTIFY_SOURCE` and object size checking, and the destination buffer size is used when the compiler can deduce it.

You could possibly do something like the following, assuming `data` is an array of size `sizeData`.

```
/* avoid undefined behavior */
ASSERT(data->m_bin->data != NULL);
ASSERT(versionStr != NULL);
ASSERT(data->m_bin->sizeData > 0);

size_t l1 = data->m_bin->sizeData;
size_t l2 = strlen(versionStr);

/* min function */
size_t len = l1 < l2 ? l1 : l2;

/* if versionStr is shorter than len, then data will be backfilled */
strncpy(data->m_bin->data, versionStr, len);

/* NULL terminate, even if it truncates */
data->m_bin->data[data->m_bin->sizeData-1] = '\0';
```

---

You should probably turn on warnings with `-Wall`. I suspect you should get one for using the `address of` operator.

Comment: Thanks! Well, the data structure that contains m_bin->data is given and can't be changed, so that's not an option. Alternatively: can I turn off this FORTIFY_SOURCE thingy right for this one line of code somehow? If not: has FORTIFY_SOURCE some similar influence on calls to memcpy()?

Comment: Well, you can disable with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`, but I don't recommend it. You should probably show how the structure is declared and used. Then, folks can tell you how to make things work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

> Here data->m_bin->data is a char where the calling application ensures it is followed by a datablock which is large enough to keep all the data handed over by strncpy().

It is unusual that this results in a valid C program.  Pointer provenance rules usually imply that this leads to undefined behavior.

If the `char` is at the end of a struct, it may be possible to use a flexible array member, to make it clearer to the compiler what the intent is.

If you do not want to change your sources, you can compile with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`.  This will disable the replacement of `strncpy` with the fortified version.